# twitter api tweets of a user returns different number than the number specified in the api

Tags: twitter, bigdata, twitter4j

Hi I am trying to get all the tweets of a page for a uni project using GET statuses/user_timeline twitter rest api but the returned result is smaller then the 51.8K(tweets) the cnn page has the limit is different that the 3200 tweet the api says.So i manually checked what was the data and it seam that the api get me the tweets i see in the Tweets&replies tab ,so if i scrool down to that page i find the last message .I am using twitter4j ,is there a way to get alla the tweet found in the tweets tab of twitter ?

Answer (score 0):

there is a limitation in Twitter Rest API, you can't get tweets older than one week. This limitation can be found in documentation.